# Why do I see a spurious border in this <td> table cell in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Why do I see a red strike through in the `XXX` when I view the following in Firefox 55 (Windows)?

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
   table { border-collapse: collapse; }
   .n { border-top: 1px solid red; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr><th>000</th><th>111</th></tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td>AAA</td><td rowspan="2">BBB</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="n">CCC</td></tr>
    <tr><td>DDD</td><td rowspan="2">XXX</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="n">FFF</td></tr>
    <tr><td>GGG</td><td>HHH</td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: There isn't a strike through in code snippet, weird.

Comment: @Rab: Yeah, I only see it on Firefox. (I'm assuming you're not on FF.)

Comment: I don't use firefox, so can't test it out sorry

Comment: remove the border collapse..

Comment: @ShadowFiend: But I need border-collapse there...

Comment: collapse will ignore border-spacing and empty-cells properties

Comment: Use separate.. look at my answer..

Comment: @ShadowFiend: But `separate` messes up the spacing. I don't want that spacing.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just tested it on firefox and the issue seems to be resolved for me.

Comment: @Mehrdad have you resolve it?

Comment: @ShadowFiend: No

Comment: @Mehrdad Change the  'border-collapse: collapse;' to be  'border-collapse: inherit;'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Firefox, please visit  https://bug98304.bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608531 for more info

Extra **tr** at the end is causing this issue.

Try removing last

```
<tr></tr>
```

Comment: Yes but what if I want an actual row there?

Comment: Then put some **td** there.

Comment: Yes and that doesn't fix the problem I'm seeing.

Comment: When I added **<tr><td></td></tr>** instead of **<tr></tr>**, it solves the issue for me.

Comment: It doesn't solve it for me. Do you actually observe the problem without the `<td></td>`?

Comment: Yes, it was visible for me without `<td></td>`

Comment: It's weird, but when I removed **thead** it also fixes the issue

Comment: Yeah, I've found a million ways to "fix" it. All of them prevent me from eventually laying out the table the way I want to. Also note that I'm not even asking how to fix it, I'm merely asking why this is occurring in the first place.

Comment: @Mehrdad, this is a known bug in Firefox, please visit https://bug98304.bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=608531 for more info

Comment: Wow, nice find. 7 years old and still not fixed!! Add this to your answer?

Comment: @Mehrdad - that bug is marked as a duplicate of one that is 12 years old!

Answer (score 0):

It is the (FireFox) problem. Try to change border-collapse property values from  collapse to inherit;

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        table { border-collapse: inherit; }
        .n { border-top: 1px solid red; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr><th>000</th><th>111</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>


            <tr><td>AAA</td><td  rowspan="2">BBB</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="n">CCC</td></tr>

            <tr><td>DDD</td><td  rowspan="2">XXX</td></tr> 
                <tr><td class="n">FFF</td></tr>
            <tr><td>GGG</td><td>HHH</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: But `inherit` messes up the spacing. I don't want that spacing.

Comment: It is the (FireFox) problem.

Comment: Put that in your answer? That's the part that answers the question.